# Backendless Handling file from browser

Tags: file, parse-platform, backendless

I'm trying to build an application using Backendless as MBAAS, i was using parse before, let's say that i want to build a recipe app, is there any way to store the image associated with the recipe in the database?
In parse you just have to specify as type of the column file and when you had to insert a new recipe you just had to upload the file while creating a new recipe. Is there any way to achieve that in Backendless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature will be introduced to Backendless soon, but at the moment you can store file URL in the column.